# How to add LinearLayout in other LinearLayout in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I have two layout.xml like

viewOne.xml and viewTwo.xml

then

How to add viewOne.xml inside the viewTwo.xml programmatically like

```
viewone.addView(viewTwo);
```

but it's not working anyway to do this.

Comment: you can include your Layout viewOne.xml

Answer (score 3):

programmatically: 
you can use LayoutInflater

```
View viewTwo = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.viewTwo); 
viewOne.addView(viewTwo);
```

Comment: Error:(30, 52) error: no suitable method found for inflate(int)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(XmlPullParser,ViewGroup,boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(int,ViewGroup,boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(XmlPullParser,ViewGroup) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method LayoutInflater.inflate(int,ViewGroup) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 0):

```
View viewTwo = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_two, viewOne);
```

inflate method need 2 or more parameters
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html